# calculate field value from 2 other fields

Tags: php, jquery, key-value

I have the following 3 fields in a form. I need to generate the result into the retailer_cog fiueld after entering the second value in retailer_commission. 
The calculation is 
(price_exec_vat * retailer_commission)

AS The commission is a percentage IS USE THE FOLLOWING ACTUAL CALCULATION
((price_exc_vat/100)*retailer_commission)

```
<input name="price_exc_vat" type="number" id="price_exc_vat" placeholder="0.00" min="0" step="0.01" >
<input name="retailer_commission" type="number" id="retailer_commission" placeholder="0" min="0" step="1" >
<input name="retailer_cog" id="retailer_cog" type="text" readonly>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to convert values to `int`.

do like this:

```
    $("#retailer_commission").on('keyup',function(){
    var total = parseInt($("#price_exc_vat").val())/100;
    total = total*parseInt($(this).val());
$("#retailer_cog").val(total);
});
```

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/F5mdh/1/)

Comment: Hi Ehsan many thanks. I have changed the code but it is not updating and displaying the field with the result. I am calling the latest jquery-latest.pack.js from jquery on the page.

Comment: check the fiddle i added in the post

Comment: Works fine in fiddle but no ton the page :) here is what i have. Am i missing something ? add scrip ton my original post

Comment: make sure jquery file path is right and wrap code in document.ready

Comment: Have it in a document. ready and this si the script i am calling from jquery src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js">

Comment: yes then it should work, the html is coming on page load or via ajax call dynamicalyy??

Comment: try with on method of jquery which is the latest and recomended check i edited post

Comment: Hi Ehsan. Mamy thanks. I know it works but for some reason will not diplay result on the page. I will have to go over my scripts and check . Many thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Hi Again. Was a stupid mistake. On the page i left the field ID out :) is there a way to restrict the result to 2 decimal points. ex 9.99 instead of 9.9945945

Comment: use parseFloat then and Fixed here is example:http://www.devcurry.com/2010/06/round-off-decimal-to-2-places-in-jquery.html

Comment: terriffic got that :) appended it in the val(total) Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this

use the value of **qty** and set the **total** using id **retailer_cog**

```
var qty=$("#retailer_commission");
qty.keyup(function(){
   var total = ($("#price_exc_vat").val()/100);
   total = (total*qty.val());
   $("#retailer_cog").val(total);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
total = ($("#price_exc_vat").val()/100);
total = (total*qty.val());     //changes in this line
$("#retailer_cog").val(total);
});
```